# What does "warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on: 'iOS' 15.4 and later, 'maccatalyst' 15.4 and later.." mean and how to I get rid of it?

Tags: maui

I've got a reasonably large Maui project at this point. It includes several proprietary packages that are all .net 6 and have this framework definition in them straight from the template:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
```

When I build my Maui application now, I get a stream of these messages:

```
3>C:\Maui\MauiProgram.cs(94,13,97,78): warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on: 'iOS' 15.4 and later, 'maccatalyst' 15.4 and later. 'TokenRetrievalHandler<SignInPolicy>' is only supported on: 'iOS' 16.0 and later, 'maccatalyst' 16.0 and later.
3>C:\Maui\MauiProgram.cs(89,13,91,93): warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on: 'iOS' 15.4 and later, 'maccatalyst' 15.4 and later. 'MsalTokenService<SignInPolicy>' is only supported on: 'iOS' 16.0 and later, 'maccatalyst' 16.0 and later.
3>C:\Maui\MauiProgram.cs(89,13,91,93): warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on: 'iOS' 15.4 and later, 'maccatalyst' 15.4 and later. 'ITokenService<SignInPolicy>' is only supported on: 'iOS' 16.0 and later, 'maccatalyst' 16.0 and later.
3>C:\Maui\MauiProgram.cs(96,52,96,100): warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on: 'iOS' 15.4 and later, 'maccatalyst' 15.4 and later. 'Policy.TokenRefresher<SignInPolicy>(IServiceProvider, HttpRequestMessage)' is only supported on: 'iOS' 16.0 and later, 'maccatalyst' 16.0 and later.
3>C:\Maui\MauiProgram.cs(101,13,104,37): warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on: 'iOS' 15.4 and later, 'maccatalyst' 15.4 and later. 'ServiceCollectionExtensions.UseThetaRexCommon(IServiceCollection)' is only supported on: 'iOS' 16.0 and later, 'maccatalyst' 16.0 and later.
3>C:\Maui\MauiProgram.cs(89,13,90,69): warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on: 'iOS' 15.4 and later, 'maccatalyst' 15.4 and later. 'TokenRetrievalHandler<SignInPolicy>' is only supported on: 'iOS' 16.0 and later, 'maccatalyst' 16.0 and later.
3>C:\Maui\MauiProgram.cs(95,35,95,49): warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on: 'iOS' 15.4 and later, 'maccatalyst' 15.4 and later. 'Policy.Retry()' is only supported on: 'iOS' 16.0 and later, 'maccatalyst' 16.0 and later.
```

At no point in any of my packages or Maui project code do I ask for 'maccatalyst' 16.0, so there doesn't appear to be anyway to lower the framework support, so I'll try to raise it. I look in my project file for the Maui project and find:

```
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">15.4</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">15.4</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">31.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
```

Again, nothing crazy. This is unchanged from the templates. So I punch-up the version to:

```
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">16.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
```

And now I get:

```
error NETSDK1135: SupportedOSPlatformVersion 16.0 cannot be higher than TargetPlatformVersion 15.4.
```

And I'm back to my starting problem: at no point did I specify a TargetPlatformVersion of 15.4.

**EDIT:** Oddly, if I add the package directly to my project as a .NET Core 6 Library, I don't get these errors. Only when it's packaged do I get them.

Answer (score 2):

I am encountering the same issue. I think what is happening is that when you are creating the original nuget package using net6.0-ios; nuget pack places that in a folder "lib\net6.0-ios15.4" inside the nuget package by default. Then the consumer project complains because it thinks that that call is only available in ios15.4 or later.

I was able to override this by appending the target version to the ios target framework. Simply change "net6.0-ios" to, for example, "net6.0-ios10.0" and the warning will go away, and nuget pack will place the package into the correct place.